# TFS Agile work board customisation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, agile, scrum

Is it possible to customise what states of work appear on the work board?

Before VS2012 we added a new Work Item State of "In Progress" So we knew when work had been started.

These don't appear to show on the boards - only things that are Active are closed do.

Is there any way around this?

I've tried amending the `TaskWorkItems` element - but the boards remain the same, and still only show "Active" and "Closed" - they also don't show our InProgress tasks :

```
  <TaskWorkItems category="Microsoft.TaskCategory">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="Active" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="InProgress" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </TaskWorkItems>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to manage this (and I'm not 100% sure it's 100% correct, TFS is a nasty overcomplicated beast).

You need to edit the task workflow: in Visual Studio, go to tools | process editor | Work item Types | Open WIT from Server. Select Task and edit the layout to have the new states, with the appropriate transitions. Save this (no, its no obvious how - just right click on the tab in VS).

then export your common configuration:

```
witadmin exportcommonprocessconfig /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs /p:"Test" /f:"CommonConfiguration.xml"
```

edit it as you've done, and import the config back to the server:

```
witadmin importcommonprocessconfig /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs /p:"Test" /f:"CommonConfiguration.xml"
```

If you use TFS Power Tools, you can update these in Visual Studio to save as a template, the common configuration is a tab in ProcessTemplate.xml

Answer (score 1):

You'll find information you need on [customizing the task board](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh739066.aspx) on MSDN.

The key information from that topic is this:

> The column headings that appear on the task board page correspond to
>   the workflow states assigned to the default task type assigned to the
>   Task Category

Check what the default task work item type is and what states you have configured for it.

Comment: Thanks for that - I read up on it, but after changes my CommonConfiguration.xml nothing changed at server side - I've updated my question to suit.

Comment: actually it doesn't look like this does it; what does it is mapping your work item states to metastates in the common config file for the Project